# SCSS not loading

Tags: html, css, sass

```
@import "base/base";

@import "base/animations";

@import "base/typography";

@import "base/utilities";

@import "abstracts/functions";

@import "abstracts/mixins";

@import "abstracts/variables";

@import "layout/header";

@import "pages/home";
```

This is my main.scss file. Here I have imported all folders and their files together. The problem I am facing is that those are not loading in real time. Is there any problem in that architecture? I need to change my main.scss file every time by setting some spaces and cutting them again and then saving the file and the whole process will load for that time. How do I get rid of this problem? Is there any rule in that scss architecture? I maintained the sequence of folders & files while importing. How can I fix that?

Comment: What tool are you using to compile this to CSS?

Comment: I guess you are using gulp and other handy thingies . I would like to see your gulpfile.js . That is where the problem will be 100% .

Comment: i m using npm init  thn npm install node-sass

Comment: where i can find the gulpfile.js ? @BojanKolano

Comment: Maybe you have set up watcher only on `main.scss` and not on all files?

Comment: yes i set the watcher file only on main.scss but this is the rule of sass css architechure .i had imported all file in main.scss @Justinas

Comment: @Arman Your gulpfile.js shoud be somewhere in your project. That is where you write your syntax for gulp. In that file , for gulp to do its job , you need to specify that the gulp will monitor all .scss files and compile them to css .